# SQL update - merge data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Issue with a USER_DIM table in a database that has references to other tables in that database like USER_ACTIVITY_FACT via USER_ID.

A problem arouse when the original design of the table did not use a proper unique identifier which actually comes from a different database's EXTERNAL_ID.

I can figure how to select the extra rows or delete them but I want to update the rows in the other tables to point to the original USER_ID and then delete the extra rows in the USER_DIM table

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_FACT.USER_ID
FROM USER_ACTIVITY_FACT 
WHERE USER_ACTIVITY_FACT.USER_ID IN (
select USER_ID    
  FROM USER_DIM
  WHERE EXTERNAL_ID IN (SELECT ud2.EXTERNAL_ID 
  FROM  USER_DIM as ud2
  where USER_ID > ud2.USER_ID));
```

update these to be the smallest USER_ID

And then execute the delete statement on the USER_DIM;

```
DELETE      
  FROM USER_DIM   
  WHERE EXTERNAL_ID IN (SELECT ud2.EXTERNAL_ID 
  FROM  USER_DIM as ud2
  where USER_ID > ud2.USER_ID);
```

after which ALTER the table to have Unique index on the EXTERNAL_ID column.

This query might update per row rather than a more preferred update multiple rows at once for the offending-extra USER_ID.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**
To clarify the objective:

```
USER_ACTIVITY_FACT 
-------------
USER_ID
2 
3
4
5
6

USER_DIM
--------------
USER_ID  EXTERNAL_ID
2        23
3        23
4        24
5        24
6        26
```

..result should look like

```
USER_ACTIVITY_FACT 
-------------
USER_ID
2 
2
4
4
6

USER_DIM
--------------
USER_ID  EXTERNAL_ID
2        23
4        24
6        26
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got the request correctly but here is something I came up with. You can use group by to find your minimum USER_ID for each EXTERNAL_ID and put that in temp table as your mapping info (OLD_ID => NEW_ID). Afterwards you join your tables that need updating on temp table and update from old to new id (Join on OLD_ID, Update to NEW_ID). At the end you can delete like you used to, or again join to mapping table.

You can check on **[SQLFiddleDemo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3e02/2)**

```
--prepare data and insert into #mapping temp table from dim
WITH CTE1 AS 
(
    SELECT EXTERNAL_ID, MIN(USER_ID) AS NEW_USER_ID
    FROM dbo.USER_DIM
    GROUP BY EXTERNAL_ID
)
SELECT  CTE1.EXTERNAL_ID ,
        USER_ID AS OLD_USER_ID ,
        NEW_USER_ID
INTO #mapping
FROM dbo.USER_DIM
INNER JOIN CTE1 ON dbo.USER_DIM.EXTERNAL_ID = CTE1.EXTERNAL_ID;

--check your mappings
SELECT * FROM #mapping;

--update fact table based on join on mappings
UPDATE fact 
SET fact.USER_ID = src.NEW_USER_ID
FROM #mapping src
INNER JOIN dbo.USER_ACTIVITY_FACT fact ON src.OLD_USER_ID = fact.USER_ID;

--check your fact table
SELECT * FROM USER_ACTIVITY_FACT;

--delete from dim based on mappings missmatch
DELETE d
FROM dbo.USER_DIM d
INNER JOIN #mapping m ON d.USER_ID = m.OLD_USER_ID
WHERE m.NEW_USER_ID <> m.OLD_USER_ID;

--check your dim table
SELECT * FROM dbo.USER_DIM;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UPDATE from a derived table with [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause

```
DECLARE @delUserID TABLE(delUserID int) 

UPDATE x
SET x.USER_ID = x.NewUserID
OUTPUT DELETED.USER_ID INTO @delUserID
FROM (  
      SELECT f.USER_ID, 
             MIN(f.USER_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY u.EXTERNAL_ID) AS NewUserID             
      FROM dbo.USER_ATIVITY_FACT f JOIN dbo.USER_DIM u ON f.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
      ) x
WHERE x.USER_ID != x.NewUserID      

DELETE USER_DIM
WHERE USER_ID IN (SELECT delUserID FROM @delUserID)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49a37/3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. @Nenad solutions works but I have to push this through liquibase scripts and was not sure if the SQL Server functions would work.  I checked this against **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdde7/4)** as well.

```
--prepare data and insert into #mapping temp table from dim
UPDATE USER_ACTIVITY_FACT 
SET 
    USER_ID = (SELECT 
            MIN(ud1.USER_ID)
        FROM
            USER_DIM as ud1
        WHERE
            ud1.EXTERNAL_ID = (SELECT 
                    MIN(ud2.EXTERNAL_ID)
                FROM
                    USER_DIM as ud2,
                    USER_DIM as ud3
                WHERE
                    ud2.EXTERNAL_ID = ud3.EXTERNAL_ID
                        AND ud3.USER_ID = USER_ACTIVITY_FACT.USER_ID)
); 

--delete from dim based on mappings missmatch
DELETE      
  FROM USER_DIM  
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM USER_DIM t1 
     WHERE t1.EXTERNAL_ID = USER_DIM.EXTERNAL_ID
 AND USER_DIM.USER_ID > t1.USER_ID);
```